# why is my background color on top of my imgs?

Tags: html, css, image, background-color

My problem is that the imgs behind  the background color. As it is, padding-top:100px.. when I had padding top at 0px it was fine. This happens even though two of my divs have no background color. When i inspect element the img is clearly behind the background

HTML

```
<div id="hiw1">
  <img src="images/collegemap.png" class="hiwImg" />
  <h3>Choose the colleges</h3>
  <h5>Pick as many schools as you'd like.</h5>
</div>

<div id="hiw2">
  <img src="images/collegemap.png" class="hiwImg" />
  <h3>Book your <span class="green">Visits</span>.</h3>
  <h5>Make sure to find a date you are available.</h5>
</div>

<div id="hiw3">
  <img src="images/collegemap.png" class="hiwImg" />
  <h3>Take the IV survey.</h3>
  <h5>This helps us match you to the right Insider.</h5>
</div>

<div id="hiw4">
  <img src="images/collegemap.png" class="hiwImg" />
  <h3>Meet your Insider and enjoy!</h3>
  <h5>Don't forget to tip!</h5>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hiwImg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
}
#hiw1 {
  background-color: none;
}
#hiw2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
#hiw3 {
  background-color: none;
}
#hiw4 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Here's a version of your code you've provided. http://plnkr.co/edit/5EDIfzMehJSYTJIyM3mI?p=preview

Can you format the code you've provided better? It seems a bit off layout wise right now.

Comment: This is what I see: http://jsbin.com/zejaf/1/. How do you want it to be different? What exactly do you want to see instead?

Comment: I just don't see any image behind a background color

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z-index` property to change your image layer but from what I see there is no problem with your code.

```
.hiwImg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  z-index:100;
}
#hiw1 {
  background-color: none;
}
#hiw2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
#hiw3 {
  background-color: none;
}
#hiw4 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Here is the link http://embed.plnkr.co/IouCZgUxWhkOWy0RJBGI/preview